# Extjs Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, extjs, stack

I know that probably somewhere in my code I was so brilliant again that I have managed to write a recursive block of code. But I am enable to find where this is situated. The Chrome error console only gives me the info that the error occurred at `app.js` line:1234. How can I trace(debug) which part of my code is responsible for the error? Is there any chance to view the stack in the browser?

Comment: this error accrues because of infinite loop.so please check your code is there is any loop and it should not go infinite.

Comment: Even this error occurs, when you reference your exsisting view (xtype) in other view.js files or referencing a view file within itself causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find infinite loops, I do the following:

1. Open the page
2. Open dev tools
3. Set a breakpoint for the function that i believe is causing the problems
4. Reload the page (this way, you can break on the first time the function is called, often helpful)
5. Perform the action
6. Debug as normal (step, continue etc..)

To view the function call stack, click the "Sources" tab at the top of chrome's dev tools. When your program hits your break point, or you click the pause button (looks like this: | |), you can click the triangle "call stack" item on the right panel. This will show you what functions are currently on the stack.

To view the actual stack with variable data, you need to record a profile or a timeline. To record a profile, click the "profile" tab, and click "take heap snapshot". I like to wait until my program has hit the break point for the area i believe is the problem, then take a snapshot. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#three-snapshot-technique) for details on snapshotting.

Recording a timeline can be helpful to. Timelines let you record all the events, frames, and memory allocations that occur over a time period. To take one, click the Timeline tab. Then, click the black circular icon at the bottom, next to the magnifying-glass icon. The icon will turn red, indicating that it is recording. At this point, you should perform the action you believe is causing the trouble, and immediately after, click the button again to stop the recording. Combining the timeline with standard debugging techniques allows you perform a rather nifty trick. You can set breakpoints, start recording a timeline, and then manually step through your code. This allows you to pause execution of your code, stop recording the timeline, and review what's going on.

Comment: Was my answer not correct?

Answer (score 2):

In ExtJs an infinite loop happens in the specific case when a class file starts with `Ext.create(` instead of `Ext.define(`.

Maybe this is the case here ?

Answer (score 1):

My issue was having a Ext.create instead of Ext.define, like another user pointed out.